# Bitly API - JavaScript function to open new window

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using a script i [found here](https://github.com/dhirajbodicherla/sampletest/blob/master/index.html) to dynamically generate short link for my Tweet buttons and it works perfectly well, but the only thing i cant seem to do is create the link to open in either a new tab or preferably a popup window.

I have tried several variations of the window.location section of the script but so far I've had no luck. If anybody could point me in the right direct I'd be very grateful.

This is the script I am using...

```
<script>
    var TweetThisLink = {
        shorten: function(e) {
            // this stops the click, which will later be handled in the  response method
            e.preventDefault();
            // find the link starting at the second 'http://'
            var url = this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf('http:', 5));
            BitlyClient.shorten(url, 'TweetThisLink.response');
        },

        response: function(data) {
            var bitly_link = null;
            for (var r in data.results) {
                bitly_link = data.results[r]['shortUrl'];
                break;
            }
            var tweet_text = "Text for the Tweet goes here"

            window.location = "http://twitter.com/home?status=" + encodeURIComponent(tweet_text + ' ' + bitly_link + " #Hashtag1 #Hashtag2");

        }
    }

    jQuery('.tweetlink').bind('click', TweetThisLink.shorten);
</script>
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Normally you could just do `window.open`:

```
window.open("http://twitter.com/home?status=" + encodeURIComponent(tweet_text + ' ' + bitly_link + " #Hashtag1 #Hashtag2");
```

BUT, since you are doing an ajax call before this happens, chances are that this window popup will be blocked by the browser, since the `window.open` command is no longer associated with the click (browsers allow a certain time before a `window.open` command falls under non-initiated "popup").

A solution would be to first open the window on click (in your shorten function):

```
var win = window.open('about:blank');
```

And then redirect in your response function:

```
win.location = 'http://twitter.com/etc...';
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/usovik/1

Comment: Hi David, Many thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. Please forgive me as my JS skills are minimal, but where exactly in the shorten function would you suggest i place the window.open? and likewise with the win.location in the response? Then do i still use the jquery bind to join the shortened link?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for

```
window.open("http://example.com");
```